# Prior predictive distribution usage

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior

I understand the mechanics and math behind prior predictive distributions, but I don't understand its practical uses. Theoretically and application wise, what is its purpose?

Comment: It predicts what the data should look like, a priori, and hence can assess whether or not the actual data is compatible with this Bayesian model.

Comment: @Xi'an so would standard practice be to compare the prior predictive distribution to the data at hand? Could you expand on assessing compatibility with a Bayesian model by this comparison?

Comment: I personally prefer to use the prior predictive distribution to select the prior distribution. Because it's more concrete to have a prior belief on the data rather than a prior belief on the parameters.